# LeakCanary 2: Does one manually have to watch objects?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I just added Leak Canary 2 to my app `build.gradle` as described in the [official docs](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/getting_started/):

```
dependencies {
  // debugImplementation because LeakCanary should only run in debug builds.
  debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.2'
}
```

Now, when I run my app and check the logcat, I can find

```
2020-03-22 18:20:31.858 2401-2401/? D/LeakCanary: Installing AppWatcher
```

so the installation worked.

But is that everything I need? Or do I in addition have to watch objects manually using `AppWatcher.objectWatcher.watch`? That's not clear to me. Currently no issues are report by LeakCanary to me, but I doubt I did everything that perfect.

Comment: Great question (and great responses). I'm updating the docs to make this more clear: https://github.com/square/leakcanary/pull/1786/files#diff-a2e0f2893b70992c6087c2b17584ff57R21-R26

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes, it will automatically detect leaked `Activity`, `Fragment`, `Fragment` view (the `View` returned from the Fragment's `onCreateView` method), and `ViewModel` instances (per the [docs](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/api/leakcanary-object-watcher-android/leakcanary/-app-watcher/-config/#properties) for `Config` and the [source](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/892f356b71289d48cb0bfc0f4c26fe150f53f232/leakcanary-object-watcher-android-androidx/src/main/java/leakcanary/internal/AndroidXFragmentDestroyWatcher.kt#L41) for `AndroidXFragmentDestroyWatcher`), with no need to manually watch these objects.

No, it will not automatically detect leaked instances of any other objects.  For those, you'll need to manually watch them.  For instance, this [recipe](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/recipes/#watching-objects-with-a-lifecycle) from the documentation describes how you'd make LeakCanary watch for leaked `Service` instances.

Also note that if the app is visible, it won't trigger a heap dump until it detects 5 retained objects.  Putting the app in the background will trigger a dump to happen immediately, though it will display a notification in the meantime [(docs)](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals-how-leakcanary-works/).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, that is it! Or according to the docs, *That's it!*

> That’s it, there is no code change needed! You can confirm that
>   LeakCanary is running on startup by filtering on the LeakCanary tag in
>   Logcat:
>
> `D LeakCanary: Installing AppWatcher`

I have used LeakCanary on production projects (during development). After using the app for some time with LC is enabled, you will get a notification displaying the results of usage. If you miss that notification then you can open the *leak activity* from the app shortcuts menu.

Comment: thank you! can you explain how to access the leak activity? What do you mean by app shortcuts menu?

Comment: It will display as a notification, or if you hold down the app-shortcut (launcher icon) to open the shortcuts menu you can open leak canary that way.